# nvd3 add nvd3 chart dom element from code

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the following code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CIGW0o?p=preview

in this code the html contains
`<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>`

Im trying to add it from the code:

```
 $scope.buildNewChart = function(){
          var xmlString = "<nvd3 options='options' data='data' class='ng-isolate-scope'></nvd3>";

          var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
          wrapper.innerHTML= xmlString;
          var div= wrapper.firstChild;

          var elem = document.getElementById("charts");
          elem.appendChild(div);
        }
```

but it not works as I can see the element (`<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>`) but its empty

Answer (score 0):

To add some element with Angular, you should use `$compile`

```
$scope.buildNewChart = function(){
    var chart = angular.element("<nvd3 options='options' data='data' class=''></nvd3>");

    var elem = angular.element(document.getElementById("charts"));
    elem.append(chart);
    $compile(chart)($scope)
}
```

P.S. Also it goes against Angular practices. Consider to add it into initial HTML, but hide it with `ng-if` or something

Comment: I nee to add a few charts ,and I get $compile is not defined

Comment: I guess your `buildNewChart ` method in a controller, so add `$complile` into its injections